# AS3 running an event for a set duration after button (or anything) event

Tags: actionscript-3

For the purposes of the question, Imagine I have an object onstage. When I click on another button, I want the colour to change for 1 second, then revert back again when finished.

Here's what my demo code looks like:

```
Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Colour_Change);

function Colour_Change(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    var my_color: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    my_color.color = 0xFF0000;
    Coloured_Object.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
}
```

What I am wanting is some sort of timer function to be incorporated in the above function. I haven't got any idea how to do it, hence why there's no implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `flash.utils.Timer` class.
[Adobe ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Timer class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

The following should be enough to get you headed in the right direction:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); // 1 second
var running:Boolean = false;

Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Colour_Change);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, runOnce);

function Colour_Change(evt: MouseEvent): void {
    var my_color: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    my_color.color = 0xFF0000;
    Coloured_Object.transform.colorTransform = my_color;
    if(!running) {
        myTimer.start();
        running = true;
    }
}

function runOnce(event:TimerEvent):void {
    // code to revert the button's color back goes here

    myTimer.reset();
    running = false;
}
```

Let me know if you need more help or if this example has errors via this answer's comments section.

Answer (score 1):

To further explain the Timer class as used above:

when creating a new timer

```
myTimer=new Timer(1000,1)
```

the first number in the brackets is the number of milliseconds you want the timer to run for (e.g. 1000 = 1 second)
The second number is how many times you want the timer to repeat (or 0 for infinite repetition).

Every time the timer reaches the time you entered (1000), this is will trigger any event listeners for the event Timer_Event.TIMER, so for example if u wanted to make it change color on and off, you could have multiple repetitions on the timer and change the function.

Other useful things timers can do:

You can add an event listener for

```
Timer_Event.TIMER_COMPLETE
```

(goes off when all repetitions are complete)

```
myTimer.currentCount
```

will return the number of repetitions the timer has done so far.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can use, as other answers said, a `Timer` object or the [`setTimeout()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29) function, like this :

```
// the current color of our target object
var default_color:ColorTransform;
// the delay in milliseconds
var delay:int = 1000; 

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Colour_Change);
function Colour_Change(evt: MouseEvent): void {

    // save the current color of our target object
    default_color = target.transform.colorTransform;

    var new_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        new_color.color = 0xFF0000;

    target.transform.colorTransform = new_color;

    var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay, 1);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
            // after the delay, we use the default color of our target
            target.transform.colorTransform = default_color;
        })
        timer.start();

    // using setTimeout(), you have to disable this if using the Timer
    var timeout:int = setTimeout(
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            // after the delay, we use the default color of our target
            target.transform.colorTransform = default_color;
        }, 
        delay
    );

}
```

Hope that can help.